# Android ListView. How to change background color of manually selected item

Tags: android, listview

Can You help me please. I need to change background color of my list view item which is selected manually by **setSelection(int pos)** function and I need to stay with new color until new setSelection call. I have read some topics of how to do this, but I still have no succes. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use a `listSelector` as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2183447/1051783)

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953285/android-listview-item-background-change

Comment: Is your item selected by a click? If it is you can use onItemClick from your listView

Comment: No, I am selecting my item manually by setSelection(int pos) function.

Comment: Are your list items objects?

Comment: @user1885632 : check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395782/custom-adapter-selected-item-background/19395952#19395952

Comment: exehs, yes my list items are objects and I use my custom adapter, which extends BaseAdapter class.

Comment: Effective solution in 2 lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview/37248223#37248223

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to accomplish that by making several selectors for the different states

first put this in your listview

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Then create xml files in drawable to control the diferent states

**@drawable/list_selector**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
</selector>
```

**@drawable/list_item_bg_normal**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

**@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

In your ListView Selection

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
             view.setSelected(true);
             ...
         }
    }
```

Don't forget to add **list_background_pressed** and **list_background** to your values/color.xml or just set the color manually in each file.

And I Believe that when you use **setSelection(int pos)** that will automatically uset the layout you've set as selectected.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I did as You said, but still have no success((

Comment: I've edited my code with setOnItemClickListener method, give it a check.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it! Correct me if I am wrong: function setSelection automatically calls onItemClick method of my list view?

Comment: Yes, I believe it does. Also check this post if you are not successful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800415/android-setselected-in-onitemclick-in-listview

Comment: I did as You said but nothing happens((((. Thanks for link I'll check her. May be it will help))

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (updateview != null) updateview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        updateview = view;
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
    }
});
```