# My ListView lost its behavior after I changed background color?

Tags: android, listview

All I have done is change the color of the background and I can no longer get the effect when I click the list items. What do I need to change ? The XML is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/file" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:background="@null"
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

All I want to do is to have the look as below but **with** the change in color when I click the list item:
[image]

**Update:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="#FFFAF0"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:divider="#808080"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried cleaning project?

Comment: please post the xml code of the listview

Comment: @VishwasSharma I have. I get notified when I click just that I no longer see the listview highlighted when I do that

Comment: But you have just set background color to listview. So in beginning it display with that color. You have to set background to listColor in xml or you can dynamically change on item click of ListView.

Comment: have you tried android:cacheColorHint="#FFFAF0" instead of android:background="#FFFAF0"

Comment: @T.V. It doesnt behave like normal list view. Look here: http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/list_view_single_item1.png I dont get a yellow background when I click

Comment: check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21254184/1614108 I believe this might help you understand how you can control the differente states of a listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what I'do is:
instead of using a fixed color as the background for your custom item, like in

```
android:background="#FFFFFF">
```

I'd use a stelist drawable, as in:

```
android:background="@drawable/item_states">
```

Of, course, you'll need a new xml in your drawable folder, called whatever (I called it item_states, in the example)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: Just found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color/1726352#1726352 =)