# Setting a drawable causes my app to crash?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am adding a few `selector`s to my `ListView` to give it a customized look. I asked how to do that here [My ListView lost its behavior after I changed background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283233/my-listview-lost-its-behavior-after-i-changed-background-color)

I followed the instructions to the step. However, when I set the `android:background` for my `ListView` to point to the selectors, the app crashes. I do not know why. When I set it back to hex colors, it works.

Here is the selectors XML named `list_item_state.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#808080"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#808080"/>
    <item android:color="#FFFAF0" />
</selector>
```

Here is the `ListView` XML:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:background="#FFFAF0" <!-- changes are made here -->
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#808080"/>
```

**Am I doing anything wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

create a xml color.xml in your values file and defines your color here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="magenta">#FF00FF</color>
     <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
     <color name="light_grey">#ffb9b8bb</color>
</resources>
```

then use these colors in your selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
      <item android:drawable="@color/magenta"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: apart from that, everything is fine ??

Comment: yes .. i have tried your sample code by adding these changes , its working.