# How can I change automatically the selected item in a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, selection

I've a ListView with some items that users can select.

I want that the first element appears selected, and after 1 or 2 seconds, the selected item will be the second automatically.

How can I do this?

When a item is selected, it can has a bold text for example.

I have a custom adapter for the ListView.

---

**Update**:

```
listview.setSelection(1);
System.out.println(listview.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

I've tested the code with this println, but it returns "-1". Not selects any row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a great tutorial on ListView see this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Back to the original question to select an item use the following:

```
 ListView.setSelection(int);
```

Calling will simply change the UI without direct user input.

For the delay, you can use the following snippet:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
        ListView.setSelection(int); 
   }
}, 100);
```

For information on how change the Android ListView background color of selected item see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253371/android-listview-how-to-change-background-color-of-manually-selected-item).

Comment: Note, Handler should be created on the UI thread as you modify UI element in the runnable. If you are not on the main thread, you could create the handler with `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());`

Comment: This does not answer the question, adri wants this to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to iterate through the list and change it's selector you can use a handler like this:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        int currentSelectedIndex = mListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
        if ((currentSelectedIndex + 1) < listCount) {
            mListView.setSelection(currentSelectedIndex + 1);
        } else {
            mListView.setSelection(0);
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

And then in your code, in onCreate() for example call:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

This will change the list selection every second as you would like.

If you do want to stop the automatic list selector, call this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's considered bad UX to automatically change the UI without direct user input, but if you want to select an item in a `ListView` programatically, you can call

`ListView.setSelection(int);`

> Sets the currently selected item. If in touch mode, the item will not
>   be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately. If the
>   specified selection position is less than 0, then the item at position
>   0 will be selected.

For the delay, you will want to place this inside a Handler.

```
public class ListLooper {

    private LoopHandler mHandler;
    private ListView mListView;

    public ListLooper(Activity activity) {
        mListView = new ListView(activity);
        mHandler = new LoopHandler(mListView);
    }

    private void start() {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(LoopHandler.MSG_LOOP, LoopHandler.DELAY);
    }

    private void stop() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(LoopHandler.MSG_LOOP);
    }

    private static class LoopHandler extends Handler {

        private static final int MSG_LOOP = 1;
        private static final int DELAY = 2000;

        /**
         * Use a WeakReference so we don't keep an implicit reference to the Activity
         */
        private WeakReference<ListView> mListRef;
        private int mPosition;

        private LoopHandler(ListView list) {
            mListRef = new WeakReference<>(list);
        }

        @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            // Check if we still have a reference to the ListView, and the Activity/Fragment hasn't been destroyed
            if (mListRef.get() == null) {
                return;
            }

            // If we're looping, run this code
            if (msg.what == MSG_LOOP) {
                int count = mListRef.get().getAdapter().getCount();

                mListRef.get().setSelection(mPosition);

                // If the position is less than the count, increment it, otherwise set it to 0
                if (mPosition < count - 1) {
                    mPosition++;
                } else {
                    mPosition = 0;
                }

                // Send the same message again, so we repeat this process
                sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_LOOP, DELAY);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much!

This instruction:

```
listview.setSelection(int)
```

does not work in my code.

When I select some item, the background colour turns blue. That's correct.
But when the activity is just loaded, there is not item selected automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I use `performItemClick` and the item is selected, highlighted and the `getSelectedItem` method will return the correct value:

```
ListView1.performItemClick(ListView1.getChildAt(1),1,ListView1.getItemIdAtPosition(1));
```

where `1` = position in the list