# listView items to stay highlighted after being clicked

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` that I want the clicked item to have a background color to indicate which item is currently selected.
I have achieved that by specifying a selector field

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sub_arguments_listView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

And the **list_selector.xml** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/seperator_color" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/seperator_color" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/seperator_color" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/seperator_color" />
    <item android:state_active="true" android:drawable="@color/seperator_color" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/seperator_color" />
</selector>
```

I have added a `ListView.onItemClickListener()`:

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
   String text ="sometext";
    ((TextView)mMainView.findViewById(R.id.sub_argument_text)).setText(text);
}
```

This works fine and as expected as long as the variable "text" has a short contents. 
The problem I am having is when the contents of the variable "text" is a long text then the `TextView` is updated fine but the selected item in the `ListView` will loose the background (back to transparent) for some reason (my guess is the focus is lost). If I click on the same item again then the background stays and the item is still highlighted. 
Also please note that I have two Android devices:

1. A *Marshmallow 5.0* which is a fast device. And I don't see the issue.
2. The second is a *4.2* and relatively slow device which shows this issue.

What am I missing ? How do I made the clicked item in the listView to remain highlighted all the time until another item is clicked ?

Thanks

Comment: Making Listview clikable make the items in the adapter class android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"   android:clickable="false"

Comment: Ok. I removed the clickable attribute but still having the same issue?

Comment: you not to remove the clickable from listview. I am talking adapter class views

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
     {

       listView.setItemChecked(position, true);

     }
```

This may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Example...

[Android ListView. How to change background color of manually selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253371/android-listview-how-to-change-background-color-of-manually-selected-item)

also see this answer also

[Change background color of selected item on a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview)

In your code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
         view.setSelected(true);
         ...
     }
}
```